# $on('value...) gives me "undefined is not a function" in angularfire

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I have started to use angularjs and now am following a tutorial about angularjs with angularfire. In the tutorial there is a section to learn how to use `child_added`

```
angular.module('firebaseApp').service('MessageService', function(FBURL, $q, $firebase) {
        var messageRef = new Firebase(FBURL).child('messages');
        var fireMessage = $firebase(messageRef).$asArray();

        return {
            childAdded: function childAdded(limitNumber, cb) {
                fireMessage.$on('child_added', function(snapshot){
                    console.log(snapshot);
                    var val = snapshot.val();
                    cb.call(this,{
                        user: val.user,
                        text: val.text,
                        name: snapshot.name()
                    });
                });
            },
```

and main controller :

```
MessageService.childAdded(5, function(addedChild){
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.messages.push(addedChild);
    });
});
```

When I use the code, chrome developer tools is giving an error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

adressing `.$on` in MessageService and `.childadded` in controller.

This is a video tutorial and I can see him working like this. I  checked many answers but could not find a way. My best shot is I guess different versions of angularjs and angularfire. But that did not help me either. Can you help me to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it's not $on but on than the syntax (from the ref)     myFirebaseRef.child("location/city").on("value", function(snapshot) {
    alert(snapshot.val()); // Alerts "San Francisco"
    });

Comment: I tried $on and on also. they both give the same error

Comment: Try to get rid of $firebase(messageRef).$asArray(); become $firebase(messageRef);

Comment: Still same. one video before, if I did not add $asArray(); there was problem also. I dont get what causes problem.

Comment: I get it $on is removed in version 0.8.2 so I have to change it to extendFactory() method.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd offer a bit of clarity on the topic for those who are taking this tutorial on tutsplus. First, we should pay attention to the versions of firebase and angularfire that we are using, compared to what the instructor is using. This might seem obvious, but there are many out there who fail to realize it. Whenever watching a tutorial, you should always check the version of ANY package you are using. This world of software moves really fast, and up-to-date tutorials are a luxury.

Pay attention to your `bower.json` file in your project. Note the version of the following lines:

    `"firebase": "~2.0.4",
    "angularfire": "~0.9.0"`

You can see here the version of the dependencies I used. Chances are, you were like me, and your version will differ from what you find in the teacher's version. The instructor offers his source files on the course main page. Download those files, which should be titled SourceFiles_RTWebAppAngularFirebase.zip. Once downloaded, open it, and you will see a list of packaged zip files contained in a file called Firebase Source. Find lesson-16-angularfire.zip, and also open it. A folder titled "Firebase" should be provided, and there you will find the instructor's app that he created during the tutorial. Check out his `bower.json` file, and check it against what you have. According to what I found, both versions of firebase and angularfire were vastly different. This means only one thing: we have some reading to do.

Go here and check out the releases of AngularFire: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/releases

Scroll down, and read the release notes of v0.8.0. A very important note is found here.

> $on() and $off() no longer exist. Similar functionality can be obtained with $watch() but should be discouraged for trying to manually manage server events (manipulation should be done with data transformations through $extendFactory() instead).

Obviously now, we understand that we can't follow *blindly* in the instructor's footsteps. We have to try mimicking his app's functionality. Reading what I posted above, we can use `$watch` to obtain similar functionality. However, I honestly tried to make this work, and the functionality that `$watch` delivers is not exactly the functionality we are trying to achieve. Ideally, we should synchronize our empty messages array `$scope.messages` with `$firebase(messageRef).$asArray()`. That wouldn't be as fun though.

The route I took was this: I looked at what `cb.call()` was doing, which is the following

```
MessageService.childAdded(function(addedChild) {
    $scope.messages.push(addedChild);
});
```

This call back function pushes an object created from cherry picked values obtained from a snapshot returned from a 'child_added' event. The real leverage here is the snapshot, which is provided by the $firebase module itself with `Firebase.on()`. If you read the docs for the "Child_Added" event, it says

> This event will be triggered once for each initial child at this location, and it will be triggered again every time a new child is added. The DataSnapshot passed into the callback will reflect the data for the relevant child

The DataSnapshot returned for every "initial" child at this location, is what initially populates the list of messages. This means that we can change this:

```
fireMessage.$on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot);
    var val = snapshot.val();
    cb.call(this,{
       user: val.user,
       text: val.text,
       name: snapshot.name()
    });
});
```

back to this:

```
messageRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var val = snapshot.val();
    cb.call(this, 
       user: val.user,
       text: val.text,
       name: snapshot.key()
    });
});
```

The messages should populate again on the front page. Your code should be stable enough as well to follow the instructor during the remainder of the Refactor lesson.